# Read high scores from text file and rank

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, text-files

I have a maths program that is scoring  players and entering their name and score in to a text file.

I can get the score out of the text file but cant work out how to identify each part: name as string and score as int.

It is entered in to the file like this:

```
playername: 8
```

The code that enters the player name and score to the text file is: (I have set score as a global variable and it is being pulled from an earlier function.

```
# write score to text document
def scores():
    score = Pname + ": " +str(points)
    scoreFile = open("score.txt", "a")
    scoreFile.write(score + "\n")
    scoreFile.close()
    print("Your scores have been saved to the high score chart.\n")
close()
```

The multiple ways I have tried to get it out just give me the data. I'm struggling to split it in to name and score and then rank it in descending order by the score.

```
def highscore():
# --------------------------------------------
# sort scores from text file here
try:
    scores = open("score.txt", "r")
    for line in scores.readlines():
        line_parts = line.split(": ")
        if len(line_parts) > 1:
            line_parts = line_parts[-1].split("\n")
            score = line_parts[0]
        print(sorted(score))
except Exception:
    pass
# --------------------------------------------
close()
```

This just shows the scores as follows:

```
['7']
['4']
['9']
['1']
```

What I need it to look like is:

```
['Player 1: 9']
['Player 2: 7']
['Player 3: 4']
['Player 4: 1']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: 
Creating a sorting method and feeding the whole list to soreted method.

```
def highscore():
# --------------------------------------------
# sort scores from text file here
try:
   scores = open("score.txt", "r")
   x = []   # place all your processed lines in here
   for line in scores.readlines():
       line_parts = line.split(": ")
       if len(line_parts) > 1:
           line_parts[-1] = line_parts[-1].replace("\n", "")
           x.append(line_parts)   # sorting uses lists
   print(sorted(x, key=sortByScore))   # get this out of for loop
except Exception:
    pass
# --------------------------------------------
close()

def sortByScore(inputPlayerScore):
    return inputPlayerScore[1]
```

**Update:**

I have updated the code and tested it. Now it works. I have been using python2.7

**Update: 2**

It's simple. Just move `print` command out of `for` loop and you'll get the desired output.

Comment: When I try this I get no output from the print, it only shows the close function to end the program.

Comment: @VTX check it now. Actually, the problem was trivial this time.

Comment: Thanks @Synaps, that is working much better. Just 1 thing - it now generates each score in turn then adds the next one and prints them all - is there a way to only print the final list?

    `[['y', '2']]  

[['b', '1'], ['y', '2']]  

[['b', '1'], ['y', '2'], ['yyy', '7']]  

[['b', '1'], ['y', '1'], ['y', '2'], ['yyy', '7']]  

[['b', '1'], ['y', '1'], ['y', '2'], ['yyy', '7'], ['andrew', '9']]`

Comment: @VTX Hope this helps. Check the answer.